# continuity of a function from $\ \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^m$

Tags: real-analysis

In today's lecture the sentence came up "let $f$ be a continuous function from $\ \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^m$.

I know the definition of continuity from one metric space into another but I don't really see a canonical definition for a metric on $\ \mathbb{R}^m \times \mathbb{R}^n $ given the standard euclidean metric so I am confused as to why we don't need more information.

Comment: I think I get it now. The space R^n X R^m can be looked at as the space R^m+n, where one can just use the normal euclidean metric...

Comment: I also think, that the usual euclidean metric is assumed here if not explicitely stated otherwise.

Comment: @fibo11235 exactly.